# Sleep mode issue

Tags: laptop, sleep, hibernate

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad laptop with Windows 10. I originally set up the laptop to go into sleep mode when lid is closed. I did not shut down the laptop in more than a year. Recently I opened the laptop and found the screen malfunctioning. I took it to a trusted repair location. After repairing the laptop, they told me I should turn off the laptop, not just close the lid. I find this very inconvenient. Is it really possible that leaving the laptop on, in sleep mode, could cause the screen to malfunction? Also, would it be better to put the laptop into hibernate mode when the lid is closed? Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: I've had machines that never even slept for a decade, they ran constantly, 24/7/365. They were rebooted for OS updates, nothing else. Stuff lasts as long as it lasts.

Comment: You may wish to get the machine repaired by a Lenovo Service Shop. In my opinion (I have had many ThinkPads) you were given bad advice.

Comment: Leaving a laptop unplugged, in Sleep, for a year likely damaged the battery. During Sleep, there is a small but continuous drain on the battery, until the OS shuts the PC entirely at 10 or 15% remaining charge, which is bad for lithium batteries (NiMH and NiCd are less likely to be damaged by that). If you're not using the machine for more than a few hours, choose *full* hibernation.

Comment: I agree with Tetsujin and John.  It would be a stretch to figure out how you damaged the screen.  Without knowing what was damaged/repaired we can't really say much.  I would expect the opening and closing of the display as a means of controlling the power state to have more impact than whether the laptop is off, asleep, or hibernating, depending on the build quality.  FYI you could have it go to sleep without needing to close the screen and then tap a key or touch the touchpad to wake it up.  Regardless, I wouldn't worry too much.  Soldier on.